# EF 4.1 Code-first executes queries 3x slower than regular EF in my application

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have a pet project (a simple forum application) that I use to test out all the latest .NET tech and I recently got around to toying with Entity Framework Code-First. This app already had an existing EF solution with an EDMX file mapped to an existing database and all my entities were auto-generated. This solution has worked great so far.

Note: Keep in mind that this change to EF 4.1 is purely for learning. If you are wondering what my needs were that caused me to upgrade, there weren't any. I simply wanted to do it for fun.

I copied the project and did the upgrades so I would have the same project but with different Entity Framework implementations. In the new project I used a Visual Studio extension called Entity Framework Power Tools to generate POCOs and a DbContext from my existing database. Everything worked flawlessly. I had the app compiling in about 30 minutes time. Pretty impressive.

However, I noticed now when running the app that the query execution is approximately 3 times slower than it was before. Any idea what I could have missed?

Below are the details for both solutions, as well as LINQPad measurements for both. (click images for full size)

### EF 4.0 Details

Here is a snapshot of my EF 4.0 data model. It cuts off a few entities on top and bottom but you get the idea.

http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/EF41question/1.jpg
Here is a LINQPad test against my EF 4.0 data model.

http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/EF41question/2.jpg
Notice that the query took 2.743 seconds to execute.

### EF 4.1 Details

Here is a snapshot of my EF 4.1 data model. Since it's code-only I will show the DbContext class as well as one of the mapping classes (fluent API code) for one entity, and one entity itself.

DbContext
http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/EF41question/3.jpg
TopicMap (fluent API configuration)
http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/EF41question/4.jpg
Topic (POCO entity)
http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/EF41question/5.jpg
Here is a LINQPad test against my EF 4.1 model.

http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/EF41question/6.jpg
Notice this time that the query took 6.287 seconds to execute and it was the exact same query. It takes over 30 seconds the very first time it is run. If I go to the SQL and IL tabs in LINQPad the generated SQL and the IL code are identical for both data models. This is really giving me grief. In the actual application things are so slow with EF 4.1 that it is unusable.

I ran the same LINQ query against both models. The query grabs all topics for a regular forum user, orders them in descending order by their last reply date (or the topic post date if there are no replies).

Obviously I can just go back to EF 4.0 and go about my merry way but I'm really interested if there might be something I missed.

Comment: Seeing as the LINQ queries generated are the same, I would wager a guess that the issue is in the underlying data. Have you done a comparison between the generated db, and your original db?

Is it possible that your original db had Indexes set up for faster performance? AFAIK, EF does not generate Indexes for you. (Could be wrong though, I haven't gotten that far with EF yet)

Comment: @DarylTeo Actually it's not regenerating the database. I read somewhere that with 4.1 it has to generate the database in the first place for it to re-generate it every time because it creates some sort of edm table or something for future shema comparisons. Right now if I change the POCOs so that they don't match the database the app just errors out. So for now I have to modify the database, then modify the POCOs to reflect the change.

Comment: @DarylTeo So currently both apps point to the exact same database with the exact same schema. I know the db isn't being re-generated in the EF 4.1 application. Mainly because of what I mentioned but also because the data in the database remains unchanged. If it was regenerating it then the tables would be dropped and recreated.

Comment: Can I perhaps suggest a strategy for pinpoint the problem. Compare the query timings for a small subset of the LINQ (start with "where !x.ModsOnly") then add more conditions. Hopefully you'll be able to pinpoint a single condition which caused query time to increase, which narrows down your search.

Comment: @DarylTeo That's a good idea. I will do that.

Comment: @DarylTeo Well I finally had time to try and narrow it down. No luck. I ran the simplest query I could `this.Topics` which is just the straight Topic entity collection. The difference in the time was the same. EF 4.1 took 7 seconds while EF 4.0 took 2 seconds.

Comment: @DarylTeo I have managed to narrow it down to something about code-first specifically. I used the code generation template to use the DbContext API, while still keeping the EDMX file for mapping. The queries are just as fast this way. It's only when I modify it to be a true code-first solution (generating the metadata files from the fluent API) when it starts to slow down.

Comment: As I understand it, the mappings in codefirst are generated at first run (which explains why there is a 30second query at the beginning). I'm not exactly sure why it takes 7 seconds compared to 3 seconds from then on... are you able to profile multiple executions (say 50-100) and track times for each call and see if you get a gradual improvement as the cache warms up?

Comment: Another possible thing to check - use SQL Profiler on your sql server, and see if you are getting comparable timings. (Since the SQL being generated is the same, this shouldn't be an issue, but it is nice to tick the box). If so then the problem likely lies with how CodeFirst is implemented.

Comment: And I just thought of another one - are all the datatypes between your model and codefirst poco the same? Is it possible that a datatype inconsistency has caused it to have to box/unbox some of your properties?

Comment: @DarylTeo I have used SQL Profiler and indeed the same sql is being generated and the queries as far as SQL is concerned are the same. So there's that. I can also assure you that the entity classes both the ones generated by EDMX and the ones in code-first are the same. I just double-checked and their data types are indeed the same.

Comment: @DarylTeo I actually found someone else online having a similar issue. Perhaps there is something unique about this generated metadata because using DbContext in conjunction with an EDMX works just as fast as classic EDMX. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar-SA/adodotnetentityframework/thread/5fcad8b5-949b-412c-a860-1b9a47415644

Comment: Out of ideas :) sorry. Good luck let me know if you resolve it, because I'm also playing around with EF at the moment but haven't profiled it yet.

Comment: @DarylTeo No worries. I'll keep at it. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: @AlexFord, Can you contact me? I've brought this up with the team and even with your code from the SVN, they cannot repro your results. http://thedatafarm.com/blog/contact/

Comment: @JulieLerman I apologize for not seeing your comment sooner. However, David Chacon fromt he EF team did manage to get in contact with me and I provided him with as much replication of the issue as I could. I also updated my answer below if you're interested in duplicating this yourself. Thanks for taking action!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### UPDATE

I'm completely revisiting this answer because of some recent developments.

Because of some inquiry by the Entity Framework team at Microsoft trying to duplicate my issue, I went back and retraced my steps to better help narrow down the problem. It's been a while since I asked this question and I understand things much better now than I did then.

Rather than go back and try to get some very old code running I decided to start from scratch with a simple test project. I put together a simple database with two tables and mapped them to an EF 4.0 designer file.

This generated a connection string like this:

```
<add name="EFTestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.csdl|res://*/Entities.ssdl|res://*/Entities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\sqlexpress;initial catalog=EFTest;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I then populated the database with 1000 rows of test topics and 10 rows of replies for each topic. Once I had this working I timed a very basic query fairly similar to the one in my main question. Then I duplicated the test project and I modified it using the [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) extension to generate my model objects and DbContext. The only thing I modified was the connection string to remove the metadata that is referenced when there is a designer file in the project so it looked like this:

```
<add name="EFTestContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=EFTest;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False" />
```

I then ran the exact same query as I did with the designer.

There was no difference in query times except for the slightly extra time it takes for the code-first to generate the mapping meta-data. After that initial query the two versions of EF performed pretty much the same. I was about to resolve the problem as not reproducible but then I notice I did something horrible in the question. I called `.AsEnumerable()` before my queries. If you don't already know what that does, that will cause the ENTIRE entity collection to be pulled into memory and then the query would be applied there as LINQ-to-Objects rather than LINQ-to-Entities.

This means that I was sucking an entire table into memory and then doing LINQ against it there. In cases where SQL server is on the same machine as your website you might not notice the difference but there are many cases where this would be a huge issue. In my case it really was causing a performance loss.

I went back to my tests and I ran them with `.AsEnumerable()` placed before the queries.

Now I expected the time to be slower since my LINQ queries weren't being translated into expression trees and executed in the database. However, it seems I did reproduce the issue in my question. The code-only version is returning much slower. This is actually pretty strange because they both should be running the same. I am not surprised that they are running slower than when the queries were against IQueryable, but now that they are running against IEnumerable there is a big difference between the two. I was able to expand the difference between the two by adding more and more data to the table.

I went ahead and added 5000 more topics to the database, with 30 replies for each topic. So there is now a total of 6000 topic rows and 165000 reply rows. First I ran the query with proper LINQ-to-Entities:

As you can see, still no difference. Then I ran the queries against with LINQ-to-Objects using `.AsEnumerable()`.

I stopped it after three queries because waiting about two minutes per query was excruciating. I can't seem to produce the 3x as slow issue that I show in my question, but code-only is significantly slower. The EDMX approach takes just shy of two minutes to complete one query while the code-only approach consistently takes over two minutes.

Comment: It's very unlikely it has anything to do with this.  More than likely, the issue is that Power Tools isn't generating the mappings the same way the EDMX is generating its model.  I suggest using the sql profiler to check the actual queries executed for both and compare them.  Then copy the slow query into sql management studio and measure the execution plan.

Comment: Create test console application instead of using LinqPad. There are no metadata "files" generated at runtime. Metadata are compiled at runtime and this happens with both EDMX and code-first but these metadata should be compiled only once per appplication execution. Avoiding using LinqPad should validate that metadata are properly cached.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I have done the same thing using the console application I used LINQPad to demonstrate the differences in a more readable way for the question. This is not true about the metadata. With EDMX the metadata lives in files in the obj folder `obj/edmxResourcesToEmbed/Entities/*.csdl|*.msl|*.ssdl` to be exact. In code-first these are definitely generated at runtime (as noted [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232765.aspx), see figure 1 about half way down the page.)(and as noted in the book [Programming Entity Framework by Julia Lerman](http://tinyurl.com/65t4qt4))

Comment: These comments are no longer very relevant to this answer. I have completely revised the answer as new information has become available.

I have also written a [blog post](http://www.codetunnel.com/blog/post/110/entity-framework-43-migrations) about EF 4.3 that came out recently and I've had great success with it.

Answer (score 1):

If I don't misunderstand you have two situations and in both situations you compare the performance of a query:

1. In your question you compare the performance of a query with the `ObjectContext` API in EF 4.0 with the performance of the same query with `DbContext` API using *Code-First* in EF 4.1. Now if I saw right in your code repositories for the EF 4.0 approach you have used `EntityObject` derived entities and not POCOs (generated from the T4 POCO generator for EF 4.0) whereas in your EF 4.1 solution you have POCOs.

   My hypothesis is that this makes the difference. If you are using `EntityObject` derived entities your objects are capable to track their own changes. If you use POCOs on the other hand EF will create property snapshots of every materialized entity in the context which is not necessary for `EntityObjects`. This snapshot creation might take a serious amount of time.

   So this is not really a comparison between EF 4.0 and EF 4.1 but between a POCO and non-POCO approach. (Working with POCOs (which are not prepared for change tracking proxies, i.e. every property is `virtual`) in Entity Framework is slower in every aspect. If performance matters you must avoid them.)
2. Now, what you mention in the UPDATE to your own answer is interesting. If I understand right you compare here EF 4.1 with `DbContext` using *Code-First* (`OnModelCreating` has entity configurations and the connection string doesn't have references to the EDMX file) and EF 4.1 with `DbContext` using *Database-First* (`OnModelCreating` is empty (or only throws this `UnintentionalCodeFirstException` from the DbContext generator) and the connection string has a reference to the EDMX file).

   In both cases you are using the same POCO entities. Here the performance difference is surprising to me and I don't have an immediate hypothesis why this happens. You didn't provide exact measurements though (as in the situation in your question) which would be interesting.

   I'm not surprised that the first query is faster with the EDMX approach because EF only needs to read and process an XML file to build the model in memory whereas without EDMX it must reflect over the code in the assembly which is probably slower. But once the model is built in memory (so starting with the second query latest) my understanding was that EF will only work with that in-memory representation of the model, no matter what's the source of the metadata. If you really have a big performance difference in that situation I am stumped.

**Edit**

To summarize the comments: We are talking about point 2 above which means that you compare EF 4.1 Database-First (EDMX specified in connection string, `OnModelCreating` is empty) with EF 4.1 Code-First (EDMX not specified in connection string, `OnModelCreating` contains model configuration). Result:

**Your query with EF 4.1 Database-First is three times faster than with EF 4.1 Code-First.**

For a simple model I could not reproduce the behaviour. I have created one with Code-First and tested the query time with dummy data (300000 users ("Spock 1" to "Spock 300000") in User table, `Contains("pock")`-query over user name, so that all 300000 users must be returned and materialized, needs 3.2 sec). Then I have generated an EDMX from the code-first model:

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
{
    using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter("model.edmx", Encoding.Default))
    {
        EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(context, writer);
    }
}
```

The resulting EDMX file I've added to the project, modified the connection string to include the EDMX metadata, and run the query again. The query time was almost exactly the same (3.2 sec).

So, the reason for the problem is apparently not so obvious. It could have to do with the complexity of the model or the query though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! However, I am actually using EF 4.1 POCOs in both scenarios. In the question I was originally using ObjectContext and EntityObject, yes, but I soon realized that even using the POCOs and DbContext without OnModelCreating was just as fast. The measurements were identical to those listed in the LINQpad screenshots. It is puzzling indeed. I'm pretty sure I've ruled out SQL at this point because the queries truly are identical. It's only when I use OnModelCreating (generating metadata) that the issue arises.

Comment: @Alex: Did you see my last paragraph? I just edited in silently, probably while you were already writing your comment.

Comment: Yeah I missed it. I just read it. Yeah it is definitely happening after the first query. The first query takes up to 30 seconds. Then all queries after that continue to be 3x longer than the database-first queries. You think it could have anything to do with the DbContext being created again and again?

Comment: @Alex: No, as long as you create the second, third... context within the same running application instance the model is built only at the first time. I have no idea what's going on. If you don't find an explanation and nobody else within the next days I will try to reproduce that behaviour. A factor of 3 is horrid.

Comment: Yeah it really is. I'm sure it's probably something unique to my application but definitely feel free to pull down the source if you're interested. I will keep the question open and even start a bounty eventually. I'm interested to see what I'm missing. Maybe there is a disconnect between my schema and the OnModelCreating? I'll keep hunting.

Comment: @Alex: Ah, good point! Did you create the entity configurations for `OnModelCreating` automatically via the PowerTools or by hand?

Comment: Automatically, via power tools. However I did check them by hand one by one. They looked correct but as I've said, I'm new to this :)

Comment: @AlexFord, someone brought this to my attention and I've pushed it to the EF team. I will make sure there is some response about this. Hoping hoping that you've missed something but you have been incredibly thorough. Obviously EF5 auto query caching will help some but there's obviously more going on here.